# constexpr Values with Addresses to Functions

Tags: c++, constexpr, xor

I am attempting to have the address of a function be stored in a xor'ed form in memory similar to the XorStr function that is widely used for strings which just takes a string. Stores it in a semi-encrypted form so that basic reverse engineer attempts cannot see the strings outright. I am trying to achieve a similar thing with the call of a function. The code below is currently how I am attempting to achieve it, and when I look at it in IDA the "salt" is completely revealed and stored in the file. Which defeats the whole purpose

**Basic Function Encryption Code**

```
__forceinline constexpr uintptr_t EncryptFunctionCall(uintptr_t PointerToFunction, uintptr_t Salt)
{
    return PointerToFunction ^ Salt;
}
```

**Reproducible Example**

```
__forceinline constexpr uintptr_t EncryptFunctionCall(uintptr_t PointerToFunction, uintptr_t Salt)
{
    return PointerToFunction ^ Salt;
}

__declspec(noinline) void HiddenFunctionCall()
{
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
}

__declspec(noinline) void MainThread()
{
    std::cout << EncryptFunctionCall((uintptr_t)&HiddenFunctionCall, 0x999) << "\n";
}
```

The current (undesired) result in IDA is this:
(unsigned __int64)HiddenFunctionCall ^ 0x999

Desired Result: (unsigned __int64)7FF9673A1859

I assume the issue is passing the pointer to a function so I am either asking for an alternative or a fix to my current code if one is known. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What you want cannot be a [constant expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.15)

Comment: The minimal reproducible example is in the question. I don't understand the inter workings of the constexpr. I am able to make them just normal variable definitions, if that would fix the issue.

Comment: Its in the original question now. Sorry, also 7FF9673A1859 was the specified output value from the std::cout converted to a hexadecimal value as it would show in IDA if the function worked as I wanted

Comment: You want the function to be `conseval` to only be called at compile time (and so "hiding" parameter). And unfortunately for you, your parameter cannot be used in constant expression (but it would be spot as such).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard language currently does not allow you to do that, already because it is impossible to do the conversion from function pointer to `uintptr_t` in a constant expression.

Even as an optimization this isn't feasible for the compiler, because the numeric value of the address of the function is decided only when linking, not by the compilation step.

This functionality would need to be implemented in the linking step or after that by direct modification of the executable.

And if ASLR is enabled (as normally is the case nowadays), then the numeric value of the function address even changes in each run of the program, so it is completely impossible to do the XOR at build time.

Comment: Is there any way to get the address of a function on runtime then? I was not just asking for a fix I am very open to alternatives.

Comment: @YoAvrageBiTz You can call your function the way you do in the question outside a constant expression context, but then you'll need to rely on compiler optimizations to actually do the XOR at compile-time rather than runtime.

Comment: @YoAvrageBiTz The problem is however that the numeric value of the address of the function is determined by the linker, so the compiler can't really do such an optimization either.

Comment: Yeah the XOR happening at compile-time is the crucial part. I intend to have a decryption and execution routine to make static analysis as difficult as possible.

Comment: @YoAvrageBiTz It can't work, even in theory, on modern systems. See my modified answer.